# How can I indicate "NEW" content in faq module after updating an entry?

Tags: 7

I use the [faq module](http://drupal.org/project/faq) in Drupal 7.

After I update an entry, I want to display a visual indicator (e.g. "NEW!) if the node has been changed/updated recently.

if I don't use views module.

Comment: Dont understand, please elaborate?

Comment: i want show mark(exemple "NEW!") after i post new faq or update faq

Comment: like Content content:has new in views module

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.

Add a field to your FAQ content type and select *Computed Field* as the type.

In the *Computed Code (PHP)* box add the following code:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] =node_mark($entity->nid, $entity->changed);
```

In the *Display Code (PHP)* box, enter the following:

```
$display_output=theme('mark', array('type'=>$entity_field_item['value']));
```

Set the field NOT to store the value in the database.

Go to **admin/structure/types/manage/faq/display**, move your field above the answer field, set the label to *Hidden* and the display format to *Unsanitized*.

This will display either 'New' or 'Updated' as the case may be for the FAQ page, just as it is displayed on the content list..

Comment: node_mark not show on anonymous user.